How can I access my text messages in Google Messages without attaching them to a Google account?
My Samsung Galaxy S21 Ultra updated today (10 December 2024). Now I can't access my text messages without choosing a Google account to attach them to. I have multiple Google accounts and I've never attached my text messages to one, nor do I want to.
My accounts are aliases (as is my account here, CJ Dennis is not my real name!) since I don't want to dox myself. The last thing I want is people being able to scrape my personal information from a Google API.
How can I access my messages with Google Messages but without selecting an account?


If you do a search for "Mess" in apps, you will see more than one Messages app.  You are using the first one, which is Google Messages.  Use the second one (the one with three dots).


The one with overlapping speech bubbles is Google Messages. That's the one I've always used. The one with three dots in the speech bubble is Samsung Messages. I never liked that one, and anyway when I open it it tells me it's been superseded by Google Messages.
